# divide dataframe into subgroups based on several columns successively in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have to sort a datapool with following structure into subgroups based on the value of 3 columns in R, but I cannot figure it out.

What I want to do is:

1. First, sort the datapool based on the column `V1`, the datapool should be divided into three subgroups according to the value of `V1` (the value of `V1` should be sorted by descending at first).
2. Sort each of the 3 subgroups into another 3 subgroups according to the value of `V2`, now we should have 9 subgroups.
3. Similarly, subdivide each of the 9 groups into 3 groups again,and resulting in 27 subgroups all together.

the following data is only a simple example, the data have 1545 firms.

```
 Firm  value V1   V2    V3
1       7    7   11    8
2       9    9   11    7
3       8   14    8   10
4       9    9    7   14
5       8   11   15   14
6       9   10    9    7
7       8    8    6   14
8       4    8   11   14
9       8   10   13   10
10      2   11    6   13
11      3    5   12   14
12      5   12   15   12
13      1    9   13    7
14      4    5   14    7
15      5   10    5    9
16      5    8   13   14
17      2   10   10    7
18      5   12   12    9
19      7    6   11    7
20      6    9   14   14
21      6   14    9   14
22      8    6    6    7
23      9   11    9    5
24      7    7    6    9
25     10    5   15   11
26      4    6   10    9
27      4   13   14    8
```

And the result should be:

```
Firm  value  V1  V2  V3
 5      8    11  15  14
12      5    12  15  12
27      4    13  14   8
21      6    14   9  14
18      5    12  12   9
23      9    11   9   5
10      2    11   6   13
 3      8    14   8   10
 6      9    10   9   7
20      6     9  14  14
 9      8    10  13  10
13      1     9  13   7
 8      4     8  11  14
 2      9     9  11   7
17      2    10  10   7
 4      9     9   7  14
 7      8     8   6  14
15      5    10   5   9
16      5     8  13  14
25      10    5  15  11
14      4     5  14   7
11      3     5  12  14
 1      7     7  11   8
19      7     6  11   7
26      4     6  10   9
24      7     7   6   9
22      8     6   6   7
```

I have tried for a long time, also searched Google without success. :(

Comment: Downvoting for massive failure to capitalize as well as not formatting data compactly.

Comment: I'm unable to connect your output to what your description is of what you want to do, but have you had a look at the `data.table` package?

Comment: It seems that you do not have a way of breaking ties. For example, you've got V1s taking value 8 on both the bottom and middle groups, seemingly arbitrarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Codoremifa said, data.table can be used here:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)

DT[order(V1),G1:=rep(1:3,each=9)]
DT[order(V2),G2:=rep(1:3,each=3),by=G1]
DT[order(V3),G3:=1:3,by='G1,G2']
```

Now your groups are labeled using the additional columns G1 and G2. To sort, so that it's easier to see the groups, use

```
setkey(DT,G1,G2,G3)
```

A couple of the OP's columns are just noise unrelated to the question; to verify that this works by eye, try `DT[,list(V1,V2,V3,G1,G2,G3)]`

**EDIT:** The OP did not specify a means of dealing with ties. I guess it makes sense to use the value in the later columns to break ties, so...

```
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[order(rank(V1)+rank(V2)/100+rank(V3)/100^2),
    G1:=rep(1:3,each=9)]
DT[order(rank(V2)+rank(V3)/100),
    G2:=rep(1:3,each=3),by=G1]
DT[order(V3),
    G3:=1:3,by='G1,G2']
setkey(DT,G1,G2,G3)
```

`DT[27:1]` (the result backwards) is

```
    Firm value V1 V2 V3 G1 G2 G3
 1:    5     8 11 15 14  3  3  3
 2:   12     5 12 15 12  3  3  2
 3:   27     4 13 14  8  3  3  1
 4:   21     6 14  9 14  3  2  3
 5:    9     8 10 13 10  3  2  2
 6:   18     5 12 12  9  3  2  1
 7:   10     2 11  6 13  3  1  3
 8:    3     8 14  8 10  3  1  2
 9:   23     9 11  9  5  3  1  1
10:   20     6  9 14 14  2  3  3
11:   16     5  8 13 14  2  3  2
12:   13     1  9 13  7  2  3  1
13:    8     4  8 11 14  2  2  3
14:   17     2 10 10  7  2  2  2
15:    2     9  9 11  7  2  2  1
16:    4     9  9  7 14  2  1  3
17:   15     5 10  5  9  2  1  2
18:    6     9 10  9  7  2  1  1
19:   11     3  5 12 14  1  3  3
20:   25    10  5 15 11  1  3  2
21:   14     4  5 14  7  1  3  1
22:   26     4  6 10  9  1  2  3
23:    1     7  7 11  8  1  2  2
24:   19     7  6 11  7  1  2  1
25:    7     8  8  6 14  1  1  3
26:   24     7  7  6  9  1  1  2
27:   22     8  6  6  7  1  1  1
    Firm value V1 V2 V3 G1 G2 G3
```

Comment: And just type `DT` to see the full result; and `DT[27:1]` to see it sorted backwards.

Comment: @wesley No problem. `rep(c(1,2,3),c(172,171,172))` or something similar should work. Try `?rep` for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using `transform` and then `ddply` from `plyr`.  I don't address the ties, which really means that in case of a tie the value from the lowest row number is used first.  This is what the OP shows in the example output.

First, order the dataset in descending order of V1 and create three groups of 9 by creating a new variable, `fv1`.

```
dat1 = transform(dat1[order(-dat1$V1),], fv1 = factor(rep(1:3, each = 9)))
```

Then order the dataset in descending order of V2 and create three groups of 3 within each level of `fv1`.

```
require(plyr)
dat1 = ddply(dat1[order(-dat1$V2),], .(fv1), transform, fv2 = factor(rep(1:3, each = 3)))
```

Finally order the dataset by the two factors and V3.  I use `arrange` from `plyr` for typing efficiency compared to `order`

```
(finaldat = arrange(dat1, fv1, fv2, -V3) )
```

This isn't a particularly generalizable answer, as the group sizes are known in advance for the factors.  If the `V3` group size was larger than one, a similar process as for V2 would be needed.